# How to validate for unique email while signing up

Tags: python, django

I need to check the email for unique. I've got some code:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activation'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Check your email')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The issue is user is able to signup with existing emails, I am getting duplicate emails in my db.

I want to validate for unique email, user should be notified if email already in database, How can i achieve this, Is there any examples with some working code for registration. I am new to Django please help Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [**django-allauth**](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) you can use `ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL` configuration variable and set it to `True` in your settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=True
```

---

Or if you have custom Model for user then inspite of checking email manually you can simply define that email field `unique=True` in model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

So when user attempt for signup with existing email, it will throw `IntegrityError`. you can simply handle it and send response to your template

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'unique constraint' in e.message: # or e.args[0] from Django 1.10
        #do something
```

---

Or if you want to check it manually then the right place to do this is in `clean` method inside your `SignupForm`

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', ...]

     def clean_email(self):
        """
        Returns the email if entered email is unique otherwise gives duplicate_email error.
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate_email')
        return email
```

Comment: So i go to my signup folder and add this to models.py
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(('email'), unique=True) 
It reacts to my db email records. Right?

Comment: yes exactly, it will check in your db records.

Comment: So using models i can customise my classes. Making password more then 20 symbols (just for example). If yes, it sounds great! Thank you for help!

Comment: Checking it right now. Added Unique=True to model, but it still let registrate new user the same email. Checked the db, my email field called 'email'. Maybe something is wrong with user?

Comment: you have to run  `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` after that it will work with `unique` validation